# Complexity of Finding the Eigendecomposition of a *Symmetric* Matrix

Tags: ds.algorithms, time-complexity, matrices, linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis

This is a specialized version of a previous question:
    [Complexity of Finding the Eigendecomposition of a Matrix](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/complexity-of-finding-the-eigendecomposition-of-a-matrix) .

For NxN symmetric matrices, it is known that O(N^3) time suffices to compute the eigen decomposition.  The question is: can we achieve sub-cubic complexity?  Thanks.

Comment: Does this really need a separate question? Surely if someone knew the answer to this special case they would have said so in the other question.

Comment: I stressed worst-case in my question, so I think this is fair...

Comment: Are you sure about that O(N^3) time bound?  See my related question about Gaussian elimination.

Comment: It seems from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24287/what-is-the-best-algorithm-to-find-the-smallest-nonzero-eigenvalue-of-a-symmetric/24294#24294 you can get $O(n^3)$ for an *approximate* solution.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a really old question, but it seems like this recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08805 improves the runtime to $O(n^\omega)$, down from $O(n^3)$.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, this special case is not easier than the general case.  Purely symbolically, you can reduce the problem of finding the singular-value decomposition (SVD) to the problem of diagonalizing a symmetric matrix.  One can read off the SVD of M from the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of M* M.  Note that the reduction involves only a matrix multiplication to compute M* M.  It does not seem that there should be any serious numerical issues.